# src folder causing errors in package declarations in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In my project, my src folder is under X/Y/A.B.C/src.

Under src, I have folders A/B/C/*.java files and A/B/C/D/.*java files, etc.

I'm getting my package names all starting with src, for example **src.A.B.C**.

My packages should start with A. And this causes an error in every class because my package declaration doesn't start with src.

I've tried fooling around in the .classpath and with the java build path, but can't get the package names changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using one folder up as your source folder.

Right click on the folder, Go to build path, Click *Remove from build path*.

Now, go one folder down, right click on that, go to build path, and click *Use as source folder*.

For example :
Wrong src folder selected.

[image: as]

Right click on Custom and Remove from Build Path

[image]

You will have something like this.

[image]

Right click on src and add Use as source

[image]

BANG!!! This is what you wanted.

[image]